# Ramda.when always return true using fs

Tags: node.js, ramda.js

I am trying to use `Ramda.when` to execute only if a condition is true but it's always returning true:

```
const bla2 = path => () => R.when(fs.existsSync(path()), console.log(path()))
```

Is there anyway to use Ramda.when with fs.existsSync?

edit:

Even set `false` this is not working:

```
const bla3 => () => R.when(false, console.log('bla'))
```

This is the real code:

```
const moveEnvironmentVarsFile = (oldPath, newPath) => () => R.when(fs.existsSync(oldPath()), fs.renameSync(oldPath(), newPath()))
```

Comment: I don't think `R.when` is the right tool for this job. R.when is about conditionally applying a transformation to a value, but you're not trying to transform the value at all, just log it.

Comment: Oh nice! What do you recommend?

Comment: In real word, I am trying to rename a file using `fs`. How can I do it using ramda or any functional way in JS?

Comment: What is gained? What does "any functional way" mean? `if` statements aren't evil.

Comment: Its just to keep this pattern in project...its all built using R.pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `R.when` is appropriate for what you're trying to do. `R.when`'s purpose is to transform a value, but only if that value matches a condition. It expects you to pass in three things:

1. A function which checks the condition
2. A function which does the transformation
3. A value that you want to send through this process

`fs.existsSync` can conceivably be used as argument 1, such as the following contrived example which appends "exists" to a string if the file exists:

```
const result = R.when(
  fs.existsSync,
  (val) => val + "exists",
  "some/file"
);
// result is either some/file or some/fileexists
```

> In real word, I am trying to rename a file using fs. How can I do it using ramda or any functional way in JS?

Honestly, i would just use an if/else and not use Ramda:

```
const myFunc = (filename) => {
  if (fs.existsSync(filename) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

If you really want to use ramda to create that code for you, you could use R.ifElse:

```
const myFunc = R.ifElse(
  fs.existsSync,
  (filename) => { /* do something */ },
  (filename) => { /* do someething else */ }
);
```

Comment: Nice! Does it works inside a R.pipe? Using if/else

Comment: Any function that is unary (ie, it takes one argument) can be used with pipe. Whether you write that function yourself, or use helper functions to build it for you doesn't matter. (pipe does allow a single non-unary function, but all the rest must be unary)